# MS CRM: How can I query for phone calls without Recipient ("Call To")

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

Wie imported a bunch of phoneCalls via Excel in our MS CRM 2013 system but for some of them the recipient (Call To) field were not set. Now we want to query for those records via FetchXml. How can we do this?

I tried the following, but it I received a lot of Phone Calls with recipient. Can you help?

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
  <entity name="activitypointer" >
    <attribute name="activitytypecode" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="instancetypecode" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="regardingobjectid" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="activityid" />
    <attribute name="prioritycode" />
    <attribute name="scheduledend" />
    <attribute name="createdby" />
    <order attribute="createdon" descending="true" />
    <order attribute="activitytypecode" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="modifiedby" operator="eq-userid" />
      <condition attribute="activitytypecode" operator="eq" value="4210" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="owninguser" alias="activitypointerowningusersystemusersystemuserid" >
      <attribute name="internalemailaddress" />
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name="activityparty" from="activityid" to="activityid" link-type="outer" alias="ab" >
      <filter type="and" >
        <condition attribute="activitypartyid" operator="null" />
        <condition attribute="participationtypemask" operator="eq" value="2" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="phonecall">
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="prioritycode" />
    <attribute name="scheduledend" />
    <attribute name="createdby" />
    <attribute name="regardingobjectid" />
    <attribute name="activityid" />
    <order attribute="subject" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="activityparty" from="activityid" to="activityid" alias="ab">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="participationtypemask" operator="eq" value="2" />
        <condition attribute="partyid" operator="null" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Where is the difference to my version?

Comment: Just check a condition, you writtten a condition, in link entity activityparty is null which is wrong, you have to check party id instead of activitypartyid.